# Unable to setup jenkins with java8

Tags: jenkins, java-8

I am trying to install Jenkins on ubuntu 20.04/Amazon linux. While installing i am getting error for java version. my java version is openjdk-1.8.0_362.

Error: unable to dpkg.

I Checked couple of blog posts found, Jenkins is not longer support java8. However [here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2022/06/28/require-java-11/) i found Jenkins will support java8 till 2026. looking forward for the solution.

Another approach which i can think of is, i can install jenkins with java11 & slaves can be on java8, is that possible?

Comment: You misread the 2026 reference in your table. That was "Vendor End of Life (EOL)". Vendor being Java Vendor, not Jenkins. The article makes clear Jenkins 3.357.1+ requires Java 11.

Comment: If the answer provided helped you, pls invite/mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Reread the blog post. The **Vendors of Java** will support it until 2026. As of 2.357, **Jenkins requires Java 11** (or 17) to run, both the controller and the agents.

However, your jobs can run using different (or multiple) jdk, using the appropriate jdk plugin. That is, as long as you are NOT using a maven job type since it depends on the base Java. But Jenkins has strongly discouraged its use in favor of a maven step within a pipeline or freestyle job.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. Upgraded to java 11 and then jenkins ran successfully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34557925)